# Paired Comparison of k proportions R

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am trying to perform a linear mixed model on proportions. I looked into several discussions and did not find what I am looking for. Here is my problem:

I did a sensitivity analysis of shoulder motion (joint angle) to parameters of a computer model (n=15). Oupouts are the sensitivity indices, namely, the percentage of variance of the shoulder motion explained by each parameter of the computer model. I have 7 computer models (corresponding to the different participants of the study).

My purpose is to assess the effect of the parameter (n=15) on the percentage of variance explained. I am really not sure which produre to follow.

See below what I tried :

```
fichier <- read.table("SI_proportion_Abd_Rotation.csv",sep = ";", header=T) # Page 1
attach(fichier)
fichier
```

...

```
Sujet  Parameter Proportion
1      S1      EllRx      0.067
2      S2      EllRx      0.047
3      S3      EllRx      0.029
4      S4      EllRx      0.045
5      S5      EllRx      0.045
6      S6      EllRx      0.033
7      S7      EllRx      0.032
8      S1      EllRy      0.020
9      S2      EllRy      0.020
10     S3      EllRy      0.095
11     S4      EllRy      0.061
12     S5      EllRy      0.056
13     S6      EllRy      0.116
14     S7      EllRy      0.076
15     S1      EllRz      0.001
16     S2      EllRz      0.001
17     S3      EllRz      0.001
18     S4      EllRz      0.002
19     S5      EllRz      0.001
20     S6      EllRz      0.001
21     S7      EllRz      0.002
22     S1      EllCx      0.101
23     S2      EllCx      0.080
24     S3      EllCx      0.068
25     S4      EllCx      0.077
26     S5      EllCx      0.075
27     S6      EllCx      0.078
28     S7      EllCx      0.067
29     S1      EllCy      0.059
30     S2      EllCy      0.055
31     S3      EllCy      0.175
32     S4      EllCy      0.133
33     S5      EllCy      0.126
34     S6      EllCy      0.208
35     S7      EllCy      0.151
36     S1      EllCz      0.002
37     S2      EllCz      0.001
38     S3      EllCz      0.003
39     S4      EllCz      0.001
40     S5      EllCz      0.001
41     S6      EllCz      0.017
42     S7      EllCz      0.002
43     S1 ClavLength      0.196
44     S2 ClavLength      0.202
45     S3 ClavLength      0.133
46     S4 ClavLength      0.167
47     S5 ClavLength      0.150
48     S6 ClavLength      0.078
49     S7 ClavLength      0.173
50     S1    ClavACx      0.014
51     S2    ClavACx      0.021
52     S3    ClavACx      0.018
53     S4    ClavACx      0.017
54     S5    ClavACx      0.042
55     S6    ClavACx      0.019
56     S7    ClavACx      0.018
57     S1    ClavACy      0.137
58     S2    ClavACy      0.149
59     S3    ClavACy      0.067
60     S4    ClavACy      0.105
61     S5    ClavACy      0.107
62     S6    ClavACy      0.043
63     S7    ClavACy      0.150
64     S1    ClavACz      0.052
65     S2    ClavACz      0.055
66     S3    ClavACz      0.023
67     S4    ClavACz      0.048
68     S5    ClavACz      0.032
69     S6    ClavACz      0.056
70     S7    ClavACz      0.055
71     S1    ClavSCx      0.055
72     S2    ClavSCx      0.068
73     S3    ClavSCx      0.037
74     S4    ClavSCx      0.039
75     S5    ClavSCx      0.073
76     S6    ClavSCx      0.050
77     S7    ClavSCx      0.032
78     S1    ClavSCy      0.070
79     S2    ClavSCy      0.087
80     S3    ClavSCy      0.064
81     S4    ClavSCy      0.067
82     S5    ClavSCy      0.045
83     S6    ClavSCy      0.017
84     S7    ClavSCy      0.077
85     S1    ClavSCz      0.060
86     S2    ClavSCz      0.042
87     S3    ClavSCz      0.027
88     S4    ClavSCz      0.029
89     S5    ClavSCz      0.029
90     S6    ClavSCz      0.003
91     S7    ClavSCz      0.061
92     S1   ScapConX      0.013
93     S2   ScapConX      0.005
94     S3   ScapConX      0.003
95     S4   ScapConX      0.004
96     S5   ScapConX      0.002
97     S6   ScapConX      0.004
98     S7   ScapConX      0.003
99     S1   ScapConZ      0.007
100    S2   ScapConZ      0.001
101    S3   ScapConZ      0.004
102    S4   ScapConZ      0.003
103    S5   ScapConZ      0.003
104    S6   ScapConZ      0.038
105    S7   ScapConZ      0.004
```

...

```
ggplot(fichier,aes(x=Parameter,y=Proportion,colour=Parameter) )+
  geom_jitter(width=0.25) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0, alpha=0.5)
```

...

[image: Percentage of variance explained by each parameter for the 7 participants]

...

```
glmer1 <- glmer(Proportion~Parameter+(1|Sujet), family=binomial, data=fichier)
summary(glmer1)
```

...

Then I get many errors

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
Warning message:
In eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!




Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Proportion ~ Parameter + (1 | Sujet)
   Data: fichier

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    32.0     74.5      0.0      0.0       89 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
   67109   872415  3019899  5033165 13958644 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Sujet  (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 105, groups:  Sujet, 7

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)         -8.374e+01  2.536e+07       0        1
ParameterClavACy     2.870e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterClavACz    -8.852e+00  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterClavLength  2.866e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterClavSCx    -3.414e-01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterClavSCy     3.896e+00  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterClavSCz     4.714e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterEllCx       3.503e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterEllCy       3.175e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterEllCz      -4.490e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterEllRx      -1.359e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterEllRy       4.255e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterEllRz      -3.082e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterScapConX   -5.456e+01  3.587e+07       0        1
ParameterScapConZ   -3.300e+01  3.587e+07       0        1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 15 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

Warning messages:
1: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
2: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

I tried another thing with quasibinomial family, even if no errors appear, I read that it may not be advised

```
glmmPQL1 <- glmmPQL(Proportion~Parameter, random=~1|Sujet, family=quasibinomial, data=fichier)
itération 1

summary(glmmPQL1)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: fichier 
  AIC BIC logLik
   NA  NA     NA

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Sujet
         (Intercept)   Residual
StdDev: 1.017364e-05 0.09387842

Variance function:
 Structure: fixed weights
 Formula: ~invwt 
Fixed effects:  Proportion ~ Parameter 
                        Value Std.Error DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)         -3.828204 0.2655327 84 -14.417068  0.0000
ParameterClavACy     1.719831 0.2927790 84   5.874161  0.0000
ParameterClavACz     0.792921 0.3226117 84   2.457819  0.0160
ParameterClavLength  2.147482 0.2856674 84   7.517423  0.0000
ParameterClavSCx     0.895730 0.3179622 84   2.817096  0.0060
ParameterClavSCy     1.094262 0.3100832 84   3.528930  0.0007
ParameterClavSCz     0.536507 0.3361478 84   1.596045  0.1142
ParameterEllCx       1.358367 0.3015498 84   4.504619  0.0000
ParameterEllCy       1.923450 0.2890181 84   6.655121  0.0000
ParameterEllCz      -1.725760 0.6729024 84  -2.564652  0.0121
ParameterEllRx       0.715136 0.3264127 84   2.190895  0.0312
ParameterEllRy       1.135892 0.3085995 84   3.680797  0.0004
ParameterEllRz      -2.826951 1.1019932 84  -2.565307  0.0121
ParameterScapConX   -1.494232 0.6118790 84  -2.442039  0.0167
ParameterScapConZ   -0.922509 0.4933114 84  -1.870033  0.0650
 Correlation: 
                    (Intr) PrmtrClvACy PrmtrClvACz PrmtCL PrmtrClvSCx
ParameterClavACy    -0.907                                           
ParameterClavACz    -0.823  0.746                                    
ParameterClavLength -0.930  0.843       0.765                        
ParameterClavSCx    -0.835  0.757       0.687       0.776            
ParameterClavSCy    -0.856  0.777       0.705       0.796  0.715     
ParameterClavSCz    -0.790  0.716       0.650       0.734  0.660     
ParameterEllCx      -0.881  0.799       0.725       0.818  0.735     
ParameterEllCy      -0.919  0.833       0.756       0.854  0.767     
ParameterEllCz      -0.395  0.358       0.325       0.367  0.330     
ParameterEllRx      -0.813  0.738       0.670       0.756  0.679     
ParameterEllRy      -0.860  0.780       0.708       0.800  0.719     
ParameterEllRz      -0.241  0.219       0.198       0.224  0.201     
ParameterScapConX   -0.434  0.394       0.357       0.403  0.362     
ParameterScapConZ   -0.538  0.488       0.443       0.500  0.450     
                    PrmtrClvSCy PrmtrClvSCz PrmtrEllCx PrmtrEllCy PrmtrEllCz
ParameterClavACy                                                            
ParameterClavACz                                                            
ParameterClavLength                                                         
ParameterClavSCx                                                            
ParameterClavSCy                                                            
ParameterClavSCz     0.676                                                  
ParameterEllCx       0.754       0.696                                      
ParameterEllCy       0.787       0.726       0.809                          
ParameterEllCz       0.338       0.312       0.347      0.363               
ParameterEllRx       0.697       0.643       0.716      0.747      0.321    
ParameterEllRy       0.737       0.680       0.758      0.791      0.340    
ParameterEllRz       0.206       0.190       0.212      0.221      0.095    
ParameterScapConX    0.372       0.343       0.382      0.399      0.171    
ParameterScapConZ    0.461       0.425       0.474      0.495      0.212    
                    PrmtrEllRx PrmtrEllRy PrmtrEllRz PrmSCX
ParameterClavACy                                           
ParameterClavACz                                           
ParameterClavLength                                        
ParameterClavSCx                                           
ParameterClavSCy                                           
ParameterClavSCz                                           
ParameterEllCx                                             
ParameterEllCy                                             
ParameterEllCz                                             
ParameterEllRx                                             
ParameterEllRy       0.700                                 
ParameterEllRz       0.196      0.207                      
ParameterScapConX    0.353      0.373      0.105           
ParameterScapConZ    0.438      0.463      0.130      0.234

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.36529593 -0.49098983 -0.08493371  0.46559247  3.40052580 

Number of Observations: 105
Number of Groups: 7
```

I am aware that I have many parameters with a small number of participants, but same troubles appear when this code is run with only three parameters. Could you tell me if I am totally wrong and which test I should use. Also at the end I would like to perform post-hoc for pairewise comparisons

Thank you for any help

best regards

Yoann